# htaccess redirect loops different local to production

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a weird problem with htaccess https redirect.

I have my local version, and production.

Now I have 2 version of htaccess each works good on one environment and creates a redirect loop on the other.

This one works well on production:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} https
RewriteRule (.*) - [L]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

and this one works well on local

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

any ideas what is the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Your production Apache seems to be behind a proxy.

Comment: @anubhava yes it is, any ideas on how to make a proper single htaccess file?

Comment: Are you using Apache 2.4 in development and production?

Comment: production 2.4.7, local 2.4.10 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This condition using `REQUEST_SCHEME` variable should work for Apache **2.4+**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !=https
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_SCHEME} =http
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this change.

Comment: this causes the redirect on the production server, and now I understand it is not under proxy. it is a simple server.
This code works great locally but makes the redirect loop on the production server

Comment: AMAZING! if you could elaborate on the conditions it will be great! thanks.

Comment: There are 2 conditions: 1st for proxy like setup you have in production and 2nd for standard apache setup like you have in development.